# Date problem in PHP

Tags: php, date

I have a piece of PHP that is trying to do this:
1) given a string like "h m s" (where h=hr, m=min, s=sec)
2) Add the time from 1) to time()
3) format the result to look like "y-mth-d-h-min-s"

So say the time is now 01-01-2011 1am, I want it to add "10 0 0", which should give me 01-01-2011 11am, but for some reason at the moment, it does seem to add the string, but it's not accurate.

This is the code I'm using:

```
$values_arr['regx_expdate'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()+$values_arr['regx_expdate']);
```

where $values_arr['regx_expdate'] is the string in the format "h m s", eg. "10 0 0".

The main question is how would time() know if "10 0 0" is actually 10hrs 0min 0min, and not 10days 0hr 0min??

Comment: does it make any difference in your results if you replace the spaces with colons?  `str_replace(' ', ':', $values_arr['regx_expdate'])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easiest method I can think of is to extract each token from `$values_arr['regx_expdate']`, add up the seconds and simple add it to `time()`.

For example

```
if (preg_match('/^(\d{1,2}) (\d{1,2}) (\d{1,2})$/', $values_arr['regx_expdate'], $units)) {
    $seconds = $units[3] + ($units[2] * 60) + ($units[1] * 3600);

    $newTimestamp = time() + $seconds;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It does not.

It will [cast it to int](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.conversion), interpret it as seconds and add it to the result of `time()`.

Some code that could do as you describe would be:

```
list ($h,$m,$s) = explode(' ', $values_arr['regx_expdate'], 3);
$difference = 60*60*$h + 60*$m + $s;
$values_arr['regx_expdate'] = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time()+$difference);
```

Answer (score 0):

After parsing your input string into Hours Minutes and Seconds, it might be worth reorganizing said array of values into a string that PHP's [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) can process.

Answer (score 0):

This little function may help, you may customize it to suit your purpose:

```
function AddingDaysFromNow($number_of_days)
    {
        $today = mktime(0, 0, 0, date('m'), date('d'), date('Y'));
         // today is now time return in seconds

        $addingTime = $today + (86400 * $number_of_days);
         // adding to advance it

        //choice a date form at here
        return date("Y-m-d", $addingTime);
    }

    //use it as 
      $expireDate = AddingDaysFromNow(2);  // assume the 2 is advance to 2 days ahead
                                           // return the day in future
```

Good luck!

Comment: You know you can just use `strtotime(sprintf('+ %d days', $number_of_days))` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

To handle and convert dates in php you should first force everything into unixtimestamp and then you give it the structure you want

```
$date = date("THE-DATE-FORMAT-YOU-WANT", "THE-DATE-YOU-WOULD-LIKE-TO-CONVERT-IN-SECONDS");

//For example.

$new_date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($old_date));

$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time());
```